# Class duplicated in NetBeans

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I am creating a class with the Person name, after I delete this class , and create a persistence jpa entinty class with same name, I ran the project and I got this error,

> Entity name must be unique in a persistence unit. Entity name
>   [Persona] is used for the entity classes [com.example.entinty.Persona]
>   and [com.example.model.Persona]

I have already deleted class from br.com.example.model.Persona

**why i am getting this error message ?**

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project? ( "cleaning the project" is a term from eclipse, ther should be something similar in Net beans. ) Bascically delete the class files and re-build.

Comment: really are this :), i never know why clean and re-build, now i teach why :) ty bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Cleaning and re-building the project